# Job-dsl-plugin- No such property: executable for class: java.lang.Thread for Parameterized build test

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a parameterized build and it is defined in a dsl file as

```
Thread thr = Thread.currentThread()
def build = thr?.executable
def resolver = build.buildVariableResolver

Map<String, JobParam> paramMap = JobConstants.PARAM_MAP
for (String key : paramMap.keySet()) {
    paramMap.put(key, new JobParam(paramMap.get(key),  (String)resolver.resolve(key)))
}
```

......

Now I am trying to test this dsl file and written following test code

```
public void testJob() {
    JobManagement jm = new MemoryJobManagement()
    File f = new File("jobs/PipelinesCreator.groovy")
    DslScriptLoader.runDslEngine f.text, jm
}
```

but this is giving me following error: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslScriptException: (script, line 13) No such property: executable for class: java.lang.Thread

I tried to follow the existing test in job-dsl-core (https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/blob/785de7f877fdbe8fc56b8b2423ae76ec9c59fa66/job-dsl-core/src/test/groovy/javaposse/jobdsl/dsl/DslScriptLoaderSpec.groovy#L238) to run groovy scripts.

How can I fix this issue and make my test to execute successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I'll start by answering your question: Simply "java.lang.Thread" as documented at 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html does not have a property "executable", which you are trying to reference in the line "def build = thr?.executable".

It looks like you are trying to call the Jenkins Job Dsl Plugin directly from Groovy, when it is really designed to be used as a step in a jenkins job. In the Jenkins UI this can found in the "Build" section, by adding a "Process Job DSLs" step. 
[image]

Then pointing that at your groovy file: "jobs/PipelinesCreator.groovy".

But to be clear, if the first snippet of code you mentioned above is the contents of "jobs/PipelinesCreator.groovy", that will still fail due to that same reason - the property you are trying to access is not present.